# unshift posted to object in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a stata which fills by fetched data from API. here is my code:
[image]

Now I wanna add new data to first of my table. but I don't know how to do it:
[image]

Here new data will push to end of table :(

Can everyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This will push the data to be the last in the array:

```
const tempArray=allClient;
tempArray.push(data)
setAllClient([...tempArray])
```

This will put the data to be the first in the array:

```
const tempArray=allClient;
tempArray.unshift(data)
setAllClient([...tempArray])
```

Answer (score 0):

It was helpful for me

```
setAllClient(currentArray => [data, ...currentArray]);
```